# Substitute ratios

Tags: replacement

Suppose that I have the expression `(x+y+z)/y`. I want to substitute the rules `Phix -> x/y, Phiz ->z/y`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `((x + y + z)/y // Expand) /. {x/y -> φ, z/y -> θ}` Change the rules accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general "rule" keep the LHS of a replacement rule as simple as possible.

```
(x + y + z)/y /. {x -> y*Phix, z -> y*Phiz} // Simplify

(*  1 + Phix + Phiz  *)
```